# Verwendung von "Mann Gottes"

Tags: meaning, idiom

Meine Frage ist motiviert durch [What does "guter Mann" mean? How can one use it correctly?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61368/what-does-guter-mann-mean-how-can-one-use-it-correctly)

Wie "guter Mann" scheint auch "Mann Gottes" eine gewisse Ambivalenz zu haben.

Der Ausdruck ist [biblischen Ursprungs](https://www.bibleserver.com/de/verse/5.Mose33%2C1)  und bezeichnet einen Menschen, der von Gott berufen wurde. Heutzutage wird das häufig mit "Mann der Kirche" gleichgesetzt.

Allerdings habe ich den Begriff "Mann Gottes" auch mit negativer Konnotation *in direkter Anrede* gehört. Beispiel:

> Mann Gottes, was haben Sie denn da für einen Bock geschossen!

In diesem Fall könnte man es als "Sie Idiot" o.ä. interpretieren.

Meine Fragen: Ist das eine allgemein bekannte (mißbräuchliche) Verwendung? Wie kam es zu diesem Bedeutungswandel?

**Update:**

Hier noch einige Referenzen, die die Verwendung belegen:

Veraltetes Synonym  zu [Freundchen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Freundchen), übrigens ähnlich  wie "guter Mann"

Veraltete [Anrede](https://www.korrekturen.de/synonyme/Mann/) / Variante des verärgert gesprochenen [Mann](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/hoer-auf-man-oder-mann)

Comment: Wo hast Du das gehört? War es nicht vielleicht doch eher ["In Gottes Namen!"](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_Gottes_Namen)? Oder eventuell "Mann! Gott!"?

Comment: @Roland Ganz sicher "Mann Gottes". Vgl. mein Update. Und mein Vater hat es sehr gerne verwendet ;-)

Comment: Welche Übersetzung ist es? Wahrscheinlich egal, in der 1912er Luther und der Schlachter 1951 ist beides drin https://www.bibel-online.net/buch/luther_1912/5_mose/33/#1 oder auch in der 2017er Luther https://www.die-bibel.de/bibeln/online-bibeln/lesen/LU17/DEU.33/5.-Mose-33

Comment: @ShegitBrahm U.a. Lutherbibel 2017. Vgl.  https://www.bibleserver.com/de/verse/5.Mose33%2C1

Comment: Vielleicht ist es auch einfach nur eine Verballhornung des Ausrufs "(oh) mein Gott", der gerne vor solchen Sätzen gesetzt wird.

Comment: Ich habe es nie in dieser Verwendung kennenglernt und kann mich auch nicht an Filme oder Bücher erinnern wo es in der Verwendung als "Idiot" vorkommt. Würde ich "Mann Gottes, was haben Sie denn da für einen Bock geschossen!" hören, würde vermuten dass da jemand was durcheinander bringt (es sei denn er schimpft mit einem Priester)

Answer (score 2):

Ich kenne das auch. Bedeutungswandel würde ich es nicht nennen, das ist einfach ironisch gemeint.

Die Anrede mit "Mann" für solche Gelegenheiten ist ja allgemein verbreitet:

> Mann, was sollte das denn?
> Mann, das kann doch nicht wahr sein! 
> Mann, was haben Sie denn da angerichtet?

Und "Mann Gottes" ist, so wie ich es verstehe, eine Abwandlung, mit der man das reine "Mann" etwas abschwächt, indem man ironisch einen zumindest früher geläufigen Ausdruck aus der Religion benutzt. Die Abschwächung ist allerdings nur vordergründig, denn gleichzeitig kann es auch als Provokation aufgefasst werden, ironisch "Mann Gottes" genannt zu werden.

Comment: Ich empfinde "Mann Gottes" eher als Verstärkung von "Mann", aber mein persönliches Empfinden taugt hier nicht als objektiver Maßstab. Definitiv ist es eine Variante von "Mann" (oder vielleicht von "Mann, Mann, Mann"). Dennoch erschließt sich mir nicht, woher die Ergänzung "Mann Gottes" kommt. Vielleicht steht es im Zusammenhang mit dem "heiligen Narren"?